# Getting Null values when using Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to derive a column (`Level5`) based on another columns (`Selection` and `IsAssetCode`).

`Selection` column has two types of entries - "All Asset" and "Core Asset", and `IsAssetCode` is `0` or `1`. `IsAssetCode = 0` corresponds to "All Asset," and `1` is "Core Asset".

I am trying to separate Core and Non-core assets but I am getting extra rows with "All Assets" in `Level5`.

```
Select *, 
   Case when Selection ='All Assets' then 'Other Assets'
        When (IsAssetCode =1 and Selection <> 'ALL ASSETS') THEN Selection
   End  as Level5
From ((Select (columns) from tbl where IsAssetCode = 0
      EXCEPT
      SELECT (Columns) FROM tbl where IsAssetCode = 1)
      Union
      Select (column) from tbl where IsAssetCode = 1
     )
```

Input data:

```
B1  Black  All Assets  0
B1  White All Assets   0
B1  Red     All Assets  0
B1  Black  Core Asset 1
```

Desired Output:

```
B1 Black    Core Asset  1
B1 White   Other Asset  2
B1 Red      Other Asset  2
```

Comment: Edit your question and (1) tag with the database you are using; (2) provide sample data and desired results.  In addition, your SQL query is not syntactically correct (no `end` on the `case`).  And, `NULL` is a value in a column, not the state of a row.

Answer (score 0):

Please always tag the RDBMS used, I assume SQL-Server.

The default value of a `CASE EXPRESSION` when no conditions are met is `NULL` , so my guess - all the rows with "ALL ASSETS" has `IsAssetCode` <> 1 right?

To override this, you can use the `ELSE` :

```
CASE WHEN <Cond> Then <FirstVal>
     WHEN <Cond2> Then <SecondVal>
     ELSE <IfNonOfAboveVal>
END
```

Or just provide a different condition to catch everything.

Comment: I have only these conditions. How can I skip a particular condition in Case statement?

Comment: I don't understand the question .

Comment: I have four columns in the table

Comment: Read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use COUNT() and GROUP BY to get the desired count

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN selection = 'All Assets' 
            THEN 'Other Assets'
            WHEN (isassetcode = 1 AND selection <> 'All Assets') 
            THEN selection
        END AS Level5,
       COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM table --or sub-query
 GROUP BY list all columns in the select that corresponds the *,
          CASE WHEN selection = 'All Assets' 
               THEN 'Other Assets'
               WHEN (isassetcode = 1 AND selection <> 'All Assets') 
               THEN selection
           END
```